# How to check with a class method if my input is valid

Tags: python

In this program, I have a class to represent a volume (containing a quantity and a unit). I'm getting this error when I run it, and when I attempt the following in the interpreter:

```
>>> A = (10, "mil")
>>> print(A)
Error: <repr(<__main__.Volume at 0x9ab7cc0>) failed: TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type NoneType)>
```

I need to fix this error before I can check if my other methods work but I can't seem to find how to fix this.  Here is my code:

```
class Volume(object):

    def __init__ (self, m = 0, u = "ml"):
        self.__magnitude = m
        self.__units = u

    def is_valid (self): #checks if the volume and units are valid
        if type(self.__magnitude) == int and type(self.__units) == str:
            if self.__units == "ml" or self.__units == "oz":
                if self.__magnitude < 0:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False

    def __repr__ (self):
        if Volume.is_valid(self):
            return str(self.__magnitude) + " " + str(self.__units) #needs fix    

    def __str__ (self):
        if Volume.is_valid(self):
            return round(self.__repr__(),3) #fix    

    def units (self): #returns the units of the volume
        if Volume.is_valid(self):
            return self.__units

    def magnitude (self): #returns the magnitude of the volume
        if Volume.is_valid(self):
            return self.__magnitude

    def metric (self): #transforms the magnitude into metric system if needed
        if Volume.is_valid(self):
            if self.__units == "ml":
                return self.__units
            elif self.__units == "oz":
                mil = self.__units / 0.033814
                return mil

    def customary (self): #transforms the magnitude into customary if needed
        if Volume.is_valid(self):
            if self.__units == "oz":
                return self.__units
            elif self.__units == "ml":
                ozs = self.__units * 0.033814
                return ozs

    def __add__ (self, v2): #adds to magnitude using an int or another volume
        if Volume.is_valid(self):
            if isinstance(v2, Volume):
                if Volume.is_valid(v2): #check if V2 is valid
                    if self.__units == v2.__units:
                        return Volume(self.__magnitude + v2.__magnitude, 
                                      self.__units)
                    else:
                        if v2.__units == 'ml':
                            v3 = v2.customary()
                            return Volume(self.__magnitude + v3.__magnitude, 
                                          self.__units)
                        elif v2.__units == 'oz':
                            v3 = v2.__units
                            return Volume(self.__magnitude + v3.__magnitude, 
                                          self.__units)

            elif isinstance(v2,(int,float)):
                #create new Volume with same units as self
                v3 = Volume(v2, self.__units)
                return Volume(self.__magnitude + v3.__magnitude, self.__units)

    def __radd__ (self, v2): #adds ability to do i.e. 2 + a
        return self.__add__(v2)

    def __sub__ (self, v2): #same as __add__ but this subtracts
        if Volume.is_valid(self):
            if isinstance(v2, Volume):
                if Volume.is_valid(v2):
                    if self.__units == v2.__units:
                        return Volume(self.__magnitude - v2.__magnitude, 
                                      self.__units)
                    else:
                        if v2.__units == 'ml':
                            v3 = v2.customary()
                            return Volume(self.__magnitude - v3.__magnitude, 
                                          self.__units)
                        elif v2.__units == 'oz':
                            v3 = v2.__units
                            return Volume(self.__magnitude - v3.__magnitude, 
                                          self.__units)
            elif isinstance(v2,(int,float)):
                v3 = Volume(v2, self.__units)
                return Volume(self.__magnitude - v3.__magnitude, self.__units)

    def __rsub__ (self, v2):
        return Volume(v2.__magnitude - self.__magnitude, self.__units)

    def __mult__ (self, v2):#multiplies a volume by an int only (not other vol)
        if Volume.is_valid(self):
            return Volume(self.__magnitude * v2.__magnitude, self.__units)

    def __rmult__ (self, v2):
        return self.__mult__(v2)

    def __eq__ (self, v2): #checks if 2 volumes are equal
        if Volume.is_valid(self):
            if isinstance(v2, Volume):
                if Volume.is_valid(v2):
                    if self.__units == v2.__units:
                        return self.__magnitude == v2.__magnitude
                    else:
                        if v2.__units == 'ml':
                            v3 = v2.customary()
                            return self.__magnitude == v3.__magnitude
                        elif v2.__units == 'oz':
                            v3 = v2.__units
                            return self.__magnitude == v3.__magnitude
            elif isinstance(v2,(int,float)):
                v3 = Volume(v2, self.__units)
                return self.__magnitude == v3.__magnitude

    def __noteq__ (self, v2): #checks if 2 volumes are not equal
        if Volume.is_valid(self):
            if isinstance(v2, Volume):
                if Volume.is_valid(v2):
                    if self.__units == v2.__units:
                        return self.__magnitude != v2.__magnitude
                    else:
                        if v2.__units == 'ml':
                            v3 = v2.customary()
                            return self.__magnitude != v3.__magnitude
                        elif v2.__units == 'oz':
                            v3 = v2.__units
                            return self.__magnitude != v3.__magnitude
            elif isinstance(v2,(int,float)):
                v3 = Volume(v2, self.__units)
                return self.__magnitude != v3.__magnitude

    def __lt__ (self, v2): #checks if 1 volume is < than the other volume
        if Volume.is_valid(self):
            if isinstance(v2, Volume):
                if Volume.is_valid(v2):
                    if self.__units == v2.__units:
                        return self.__magnitude < v2.__magnitude
                    else:
                        if v2.__units == 'ml':
                            v3 = v2.customary()
                            return self.__magnitude < v3.__magnitude
                        elif v2.__units == 'oz':
                            v3 = v2.__units
                            return self.__magnitude < v3.__magnitude
            elif isinstance(v2,(int,float)):
                v3 = Volume(v2, self.__units)
                return self.__magnitude <= v3.__magnitude

    def __gt__ (self, v2): #checks if 1 volume is > than the other volume
        if Volume.is_valid(self):
            if isinstance(v2, Volume):
                if Volume.is_valid(v2):
                    if self.__units == v2.__units:
                        return self.__magnitude > v2.__magnitude
                    else:
                        if v2.__units == 'ml':
                            v3 = v2.customary()
                            return self.__magnitude > v3.__magnitude
                        elif v2.__units == 'oz':
                            v3 = v2.__units
                            return self.__magnitude > v3.__magnitude
            elif isinstance(v2,(int,float)):
                v3 = Volume(v2, self.__units)
                return self.__magnitude > v3.__magnitude
    def __lteq__ (self, v2):#checks if 1 volume is <= to other volume
        if Volume.is_valid(self):
            if isinstance(v2, Volume):
                if Volume.is_valid(v2):
                    if self.__units == v2.__units:
                        return self.__magnitude <= v2.__magnitude
                    else:
                        if v2.__units == 'ml':
                            v3 = v2.customary()
                            return self.__magnitude <= v3.__magnitude
                        elif v2.__units == 'oz':
                            v3 = v2.__units
                            return self.__magnitude <= v3.__magnitude
            elif isinstance(v2,(int,float)):
                v3 = Volume(v2, self.__units)
                return self.__magnitude <= v3.__magnitude

    def __gteq__ (self, v2):#checks if 1 volume is >= to other volume
        if Volume.is_valid(self):
            if isinstance(v2, Volume):
                if Volume.is_valid(v2):
                    if self.__units == v2.__units:
                        return self.__magnitude >= v2.__magnitude
                    else:
                        if v2.__units == 'ml':
                            v3 = v2.customary()
                            return self.__magnitude >= v3.__magnitude
                        elif v2.__units == 'oz':
                            v3 = v2.__units
                            return self.__magnitude >= v3.__magnitude
            elif isinstance(v2,(int,float)):
                v3 = Volume(v2, self.__units)
                return self.__magnitude >= v3.__magnitude
```

Comment: Checking `Volume.is_valid()` everywhere is insane. Do your validation in `__init__()`, and raise a `ValueError` if the inputs are wrong.

Comment: I noticed that you posted a lot of code here that isn't relevant to the question (though, given the error you received, you may not have realized it at the time).  You may find that you receive a faster, more helpful answer if you trim the code in your question as much as possible (in this case, you could have left out all of the functions defined in your class except for `__init__`, `__repr__`, and `is_valid`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def __repr__ (self):
    if Volume.is_valid(self):
        return str(self.__magnitude) + " " + str(self.__units) #needs fix
```

In this code, if the test is `False`, the function returns nothing (aka `None`) as you don't have an `else` close. You have the same anti-pattern in different methods. Either:

- add an `else` clause to return a sensible value;
- *or* (probably better) raise an exception when a method is called on an invalid object;
- *finally*, as mentioned by @malfunctionning in a comment bellow it is usually considered bad style to validate an object on each and every method call. Given your use case, you should have validated your parameters in the constructor and eventually raised an exception at that point.

---

As about `Volume(10, "ml")` -- AFAICT, this will *not* validate according to your `is_valid` method:

```
def is_valid (self): #checks if the volume and units are valid
    if type(self.__magnitude) == int and type(self.__units) == str:
        if self.__units == "ml" or self.__units == "oz":
            if self.__magnitude < 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

The only way for that method to return `True` would by with an unit of `"oz"` or `"ml"` and a *negative* magnitude (`self.__magnitude < 0`).

For what I understand, your validation logic should be more something like that:

```
def is_valid (self): #checks if the volume and units are valid
    return (self.__units == "ml" or self.__units == "oz") and \
            self.__magnitude >= 0;
```

---

As a last word, you don't need to invoke `is_valid` as a class method:

```
 if Volume.is_valid(self):
      ...
```

From what I see, this is a proper instance method and should be called like that:

```
 if self.is_valid():
     ...
```

Comment: And what happens if it is valid? technically A=(10, "ml") should be valid.
I'm going to add an else to that though, thanks!

Comment: That's correct. Just to add that it's not a good idea to validate an object when calling `__repr__` or other methods. If you are going to validate an object, validate it in the constructor, and in any method that may change the state of the object. But, in general, Python code should go easy on validation and type checks. It goes against the philosophy of the language. Only use validation when outside code which you don't trust may instantiate or change the state of your code's instances.

Comment: @Diego: You said `A=(10, "mil")` in your question, which actually fais the test, as `"mil"` is not `"ml"`

Comment: @malfunctioning Thank you for pointing that out. I've edited my answer to mention that validation should probably be done in the constructor here.

Comment: @malfunctioning  oh yeah, sorry, I meant to say "ml" not "mil"

Comment: I am fixing this in order to make the validation in the __init__ :)

Comment: @Diego ... and take some time to check your validation logic at it seems flawed to me (see my edit). That being said, it is late here, so I may have missed something...

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.... That is so embarrassing, I'm SO SORRY!!
Also, after checking some of the details of the project, we do need a method is_valid() :/

Comment: Sounds good, Sylvain and Diego. Regarding the is_valid() method, in general you need to ask yourself who would use this method. If you put all your validation in the constructor and any setters, then is_valid() is probably not necessary.